# Equivalence of different automata

Tags: formal-languages, automata, equality

I  have a question about the equivalence of different automata. I looked up the similiar questions but sadly none of them are exactly, what I need or am looking for.

I know some of these are equivalent ( or not ) but for which language class pairs does a real inclusion apply?

DFA = NFA ⊋ ? DPDA ≠ PDA ⊋ ? LBA = DTM = NTM

I want to know, if this is correct or not.

Hint:" C is the class of all languages accepted by a C-type machine" - If this is important.

I apologize, if my question isn't in a correct format, therefor forgive me, I am trying to settle in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear-bounded automata accept the class of *context-sensitive languages*. In contrast, Turing machine (deterministic as well as nondeterministic) accept the class of *recursive languages*. Every context-sensitive language is recursive, but the converse doesn't hold. For example, the halting problem for nondeterministic Turing machines running in space $n^2$ is not context-sensitive by the [nondeterministic space hierarchy theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_hierarchy_theorem).

Comment: I appreciate the longer answer, thanks again. I gave you an upvote, even if it's not visible. ( since I am new ).